# How to properly roll back to an older version in CVS HEAD using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs

I have a CVS repository in which I have a set of Eclipse Java projects where I need to roll HEAD back to the state it was at a specific time yesterday essentially abandoning all commits happened since said time.

I've tried different things, including using "Replace with another branch or version" which gives the proper sources, but where it appears that CVS now thinks I'm actually working "back in time" instead of in HEAD but with other sources which result in changed files showing up in Team Synchronize etc.  Also commits tells me I'm working on a sticky tag and fails.

So, what is the proper way to tell Eclipse 3.5.1 that I need to rollback HEAD to yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up manually merging the files up in HEAD and very, very carefully checking in the sources.  This was no fun.

Comment: Now 6 years after, The only reasonable approach is to migrate the repository to git and fix it there.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the following for individual files:

```
Replace With -> History
```

Which can be found under the right click menu

Pick the version you want (it also includes eclipse locally saved versions)

Then commit to make it the HEAD

Comment: I cannot see this for the whole project, but only for individual files.  Are you right clicking the project in the Project Explorer?

Comment: This is my bad, it does indeed only work for individual files. I'll update my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a tag in CVS, you will have to examine each file for this, and choose the version to revert to. (it is due to the way CVS stores changes, they are not file system snapshots like other SCMs).

Answer (score 0):

You did a checkin in CVS with many files and after that you want to undo that?

My solution:

Mark the files (if no good checkin after the bad checkin you can mark all) --> Right click "Compare with" --> With Branch or Version --> Dates --> Add Date --> Take Date where you know the HEAD is ok --> Now you are in the Synchronize view, mark all files --> Replace --> Check in the files again

This will not really undo your CVS checkin (history) but you get with not too many clicks the old state. And you dont have to do it file for file.