# How to revert previous updates from CVS in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, version-control, repository, cvs

Our Project is using `CVS` and its is integrated from `eclipse` and so we use `Team Synchronizing` to get the latest code from CVS but `is there a way to revert the previous commit or update from repositry which we have done ?`

I come from `git` background and so I am having hard time to find out this functionality from `eclipse/cvs`, any suggestion would be highly apprecaited.

Comment: By `revert`, I meant if i have updated my codebase with the latest from repo than is there a way to get back my local original changes in the files or not, hope this clarifies ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "revert".
The `git revert` actually add a new commit canceling the changes introduced by the previous one.

With Eclipse, that would be (file by file): "`Replace With -> History`"
(see "[How to properly roll back to an older version in CVS HEAD using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833131/how-to-properly-roll-back-to-an-older-version-in-cvs-head-using-eclipse)")

[image]

And then make a new commit.
In other word, there don't seem to be any *simple* way to do this (when many files are impacted)...

Comment: hmm...yes acutally in my case i have updated multiple files from repo now i want to undo this action and get my original local files as they were before getting the updated files from repositry.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the file -> Team -> Revert to Base. This will overwrite any local changes and revert to the most up-to-date version of the file in CVS.

Any this what you're after? (I have to admit that I find the question somewhat unclear)

Comment: Not available for CVS, CVS does not have a local BASE revision. Only works with SVN.

Comment: Well, I am using CVS with Eclipse right now, and it IS available for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean it in the sense of *uncommitting* something you committed before, erasing it from the history of the file, then *no*, you cannot do that.

You can only get the previous version back from the repository and commit that again, making it clear in the comment that you reverted the file to a previous revision.